# how to find value of "aria-expanded"

Tags: jquery, onclick

I want to grab the value of `aria expanded` in form below when click on div with class `dropdown-sort`

```
<div class="dropdown dropdown-sort open" style="flex-grow: 0;">
    <div class="form-control" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
          Sort by
```

I tried this below but i get `undefined` instead of `true`

```
$('.dropdown-sort').on('click', function() {
   var expandable = $('.form-control').data("aria-expanded");
    alert(expandable); // should give me true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `jQuery::attr()` method:

```js
 console.log($('.form-control').attr("aria-expanded"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown dropdown-sort open" style="flex-grow: 0;">
    <div class="form-control" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true"></div>
</div>
```